# Background color not displayed on bootstrap div show in IE10

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I am using metro-bootstrap,html5 and mvc5.
I have a partial view containing my tiles. I hide my partial view on page load. And i remove the css class 'hidden' in my $.ajax call.The div is displayed but the background colors of my tiles fail to show in IE10. Is works fine in Chrome. Strangely when i check the developer tools in IE10 the background color for the div is set !!!!!

Here is my html content.

```
<div id="container" class="hidden">
<div class="row mt20">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-xl-3custom">
    <div class="header">Dashboard</div>
    <div class="col-mh mt30 scroll">
        <div class="thumbnail tile tile-wide-w100 tile-green mt-30">
            <div class="mt30">
                <span class="fs20" data-bind="text: playerInfo.Name">                    
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

In my script i use Jquery

```
 $("#container").removeClass("hidden");
```

The div is displayed the background color of the tiles fail to appear in IE10       alone.

Comment: There is no way for anyone here to replicate the issue with what is shown. Please provide demo that replicates problem

Comment: We are experiencing a similar problem. Have you been able to solve this?